# Javascript days keep going over 31 days a month

Tags: javascript, html, dom

so I am trying to create a weekly schedule that gets updated every day, so it shows the current day date, and the next six days. I am using a JS function to make that happen.
[image: Weekly schedule]

It looks like this .
Following is the html used for the first row.

```
        <thead class="lighter">
        <tr>
            <th class="fit fit align-middle" scope="col">CRC/Jour</th>
            <th id="day1" class="fit" scope="col"></th>
            <th id="day2" class="fit" scope="col"></th>
            <th id="day3" class="fit" scope="col"></th>
            <th id="day4" class="fit" scope="col"></th>
            <th id="day5" class="fit" scope="col"></th>
            <th id="day6" class="fit" scope="col"></th>
            <th id="day7" class="fit" scope="col"></th>
        </tr>
```

And here is my js code:

```
    for (let i = 1; i < 8; i++) { //I tried using a loop so it we'll do the automation but it doesn't work as expected
        let date = new Date(),
            day = date.getDate()+i-1,
            month = date.getMonth() + 1,
            year = date.getFullYear();
//This is for showing the days names in the specified cells (it's in french)
        let days=["Dimanche","Lundi","Mardi","Mercredi","Jeudi","Vendredi","Samedi"]; 
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + i-1);
        document.getElementById("day"+i).innerHTML= 
      `${days[date.getDay()]} <br> ${day}/${month}/${year}`; 
    }
}
```

Other thing I noticed is when I use

> addEventListener('onload',function(){})

It doesn't work, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: You're not reading `day` from a Date object, you're showing the value of `day` directly.

Comment: You need to do do checking to see what month it is (if it has 28, 30 or 31 days), what day it is (if it is that month, reset the day to be 1 and work with your I value there. 

Note: there are many other ways to do this (through the use of libraries.

Comment: Your loop keeps incrementing the date value, so that's expected. If you can use `moment` library, it's a lot easier by using `add()` utility method of `moment` to get next date in the sequence (it automatically handles end of month etc.).

Comment: @berkobienb no, they do not need to check that themselves. The Date object has this kind of “roll-over” logic already built-in. `date.setDate(35)` will automatically move the date ahead into the next month. The mistake here simply is that the `day` value was used, and that was not arrived by calling the `setDate` method, but by simple addition.

Comment: `addEventListener('onload',function(){})` is not working because the `on` prefix is not necessary. You only use it if you add the event directly onto an element like: `button.onclick= ...`.

Comment: I kind of get where the problem is, but all this is somehow new to me, I'll look the moment.js up and try using it.

Comment: A library is not needed for the task, just do `date.setDate(date.getDate()+1); day = date.getdate();`. That way the Date object can calculate a correct date for `day` value. If you're using dates elsewhere in your code, moment.js might be useful, though.

Comment: @Teemu But this only gives me the date of the next day, how can I loop that ? Can u modify my code or show me how to please?

Comment: @Teemu ok I just fixed it, I had to use `date.setDate(date.getDate()+i-1);` and then use the `day = date.getdate();`. Thanks a lot, because I tried using libraries but got lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the guys on the comments suggested, I tried using libraries (dayjs to be exact) but couldn't figure out how to, as I haven't learned that yet. 
And as per @Teemu suggestion (with a little modification for the whole week) I used `date.setDate(date.getDate()+i-1);` then used `day=date.getDate()` for the day value, and it worked. 
From a little search I've found that `setDate` method takes an integer of the 'day' of the month as an argument. 
Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setdate.asp 
Final function looked like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load',function () {
    for (let i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
        let date = new Date();
        date.setDate(date.getDate()+i-1);
         let day = date.getDate(),
            month = date.getMonth() + 1,
            year = date.getFullYear();
        let days=["Dimanche","Lundi","Mardi","Mercredi","Jeudi","Vendredi","Samedi"];
        document.getElementById("day"+i).innerHTML=
            `${days[date.getDay()]} <br> ${day}/${month}/${year}`;
    }
})
```

Ps: I fixed the `addEventListener('onload',function(){})` problem by using `load` for the type argument, thanks to @Reyno for the clarification.